# MS SQL - cursor для update - непонятная ошибка

Tags: sql-server

Здравствуйте!
Прошу помощи, самостоятельно разобраться не получилось.
Вот кусочек кода, в котором вылезает ошибка Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 37
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'. Однако на самом деле она явно не там.
Если удалить выборку из таблицы, update сам по себе работает. Если удалить update, сама по себе выборка select (см. закомментированную строку) тоже работает.
А всё вместе работать не хочет. Почему? Может быть, я что-то не знаю об особенностях курсора?
Спасибо.

```
DECLARE @userIDweek int, @mailIDweek int, @brandIDweek int  
DECLARE @cur_twoweeks CURSOR  
DECLARE @Today DATETIME;   
DECLARE @TwoWeeksAgo DATETIME;  
SET @Today = GETDATE();  
SET @TwoWeeksAgo = DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE());   

SET @cur_twoweeks = CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR  
SELECT userID, mailID, saleByBrandBrandID1
FROM UserTableWith5suggestions
where saleByBrandBrandID1 is not null

OPEN @cur_twoweeks
FETCH @cur_twoweeks into @userIDweek, @mailIDweek, @brandIDweek
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
UPDATE UserTableWith5suggestions
    SET saleTitle = s.title,
        saleImageUrl = s.imageUrl,
        mostViewPeriod14Days = count(sv.saleid),
        saleGuid = s.guid,
        brandID = br.id,
        brandTitle = br.title
        --SELECT s.title,s.imageUrl,s.guid, br.id, br.title,count(sv.saleid)
    FROM dbo.Sales s JOIN dbo.KEY_BrandcategoryToSale b_key ON s.id = b_key.saleId 
    JOIN dbo.Brands br ON s.BrandId = br.Id 
    JOIN dbo.SaleView sv ON s.id = sv.saleId 
    JOIN dbo.SalesToMall stm ON s.id = stm.saleId 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SaleView sv2 on sv2.id = sv.id and sv2.userId = @userIDweek
    WHERE sv.Date BETWEEN @TwoWeeksAgo 
    AND @Today 
    AND sv2.id IS NULL 
    AND s.isActive = 1
    AND stm.mallId = @mailIDweek
    AND br.id != @brandIDweek
    GROUP BY s.title, s.imageUrl, s.guid, br.title, br.id, stm.mallId,sv2.userId
    ORDER BY count(sv.saleid) desc
FETCH @cur_twoweeks into @userIDweek, @mailIDweek, @brandIDweek
END
CLOSE @cur_twoweeks
DEALLOCATE @cur_twoweeks
```

Comment: Вот например ман по UPDATE для MS SQL 2008: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523(v=sql.105).aspx - попробуйте там найти хоть полслова про GROUP BY...

Comment: Akina, два упоминания есть.

Comment: НИ одно из этих двух упоминаний не относится к описанию запроса. И это ещё хорошо, что на сайте нет рекламы - а то упоминаний могло бы быть и больше.